# using named models in symfit python module for fitting with a gaussian distribution

Tags: python, gaussian, symfit

I am trying to write a code for fitting two data set  with two different equation with some shared parameters simultaneously with symfit module. it is too complicated to show it here so I show another code with the same command and simpler. Here I tried to fit a series of data with a linear function but with a gaussian distribution in slope.
Here is the code:

```
 `
import symfit as sf
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit, Model, Ge, CallableModel
from symfit.core.minimizers import BFGS, BasinHopping, NelderMead, DifferentialEvolution
xd= [1.1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 19, 25, 32, 44]
yd= [5.5, 8, 11, 14, 18, 22, 28, 35,45, 69, 110]
pi=3.14
x, y = variables('x, y')
a = sf.Parameter('a',value=3)
b = sf.Parameter('b',value=0.7)
sigma= sf.Parameter('sigma',value=0.7)
res=0
norm=0
for i in range(1,5):
    atemp= (a + ((i-1)*3*sigma/2))
    gauss= sf.exp(-(atemp-a)**2/(2*(sigma**2)))/sf.sqrt(2*pi*(sigma**2))
    res= res+ gauss* (atemp * x + b) 
    norm= norm + gauss
    if i == 4:
        firstres= res
        firstnorm= norm
        res=0
        norm=0

funfit = Model({y: (firstres/firstnorm)})

fit = Fit(funfit, x= xd, y=yd, minimizer=[NelderMead, BFGS])
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(" Best-Fit Parameters: ", fit_result)
```

`

and this is what I got this error
"NameError: name 'DiracDelta' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing `Model` with `GradientModel` or even `CallableModel`. The problem arises because by default the Hessian of the model is computed and for a gaussian this produces a `DiracDelta` which is not simplified away. Using either of these other models does not cause the Hessian to be calculated and so should solve the problem. So,

```
from symfit import CallableModel

funfit = CallableModel({y: (firstres/firstnorm)})
```

Also, which version are you using? In `symfit >= 0.5.2` this should no longer be happening so I would be curious to know :).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used Symfit 0.5.2. How can I call these models?